# PHP - How do you get today but from the last week?

Tags: php, date

For example, today is Thursday, is there a `date()` or `strtotime()` usage that allows me to know last Thursday date?

When executed today (01-22-2015) it should return 01-15-2015

And if I execute that script tomorrow it should return the last week's friday, 01-16-2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 week'))."\n";
```

You can look at other examples with `strtotime()` at [php.net](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php)

If you want, you can also use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for this purpose:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1W'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
```

In this example `'P1W'` means `1 week period`. About `DateInterval` format you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php).

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code

```
<?php

echo date("Y-m-d",mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")-7, date("Y")));

?>
```

Comment: this is a clean solution

Comment: @onegun: calling 5 functions is clean solution?

Comment: clean does not mean best and efficient, to new beginners, i believe this kind of solution is easily understandable and obvious